# MSSQL not matching phone numbers with spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I'm trying to write an SQL query for SQL Express that will look up a phone number from the client's database. The issue I'm having is that some of the numbers in the database have spaces in them, but the number that I need to match with does not.

My SQL query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT [FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[CompanyName]
FROM [dbo].[People] AS p
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Companies] AS l
ON p.CompanyId = l.[CompanyId]
WHERE p.[Telephone] LIKE '01279800101' OR p.[Mobile] LIKE '01279800101'
```

Where 01279800101 is the number I need to find the company name for.
This query does not match the record when [dbo].[People].[Telephone] is 01279 800 101

How can I make the query ignore spaces within the string?

Comment: Whenever even remotely possible, don't make the query ignore the spaces.  Instead, clean the data before it is stored in the DB.  Then you don't have processing logic scattered through your queries, you can index the cleaned fields, etc, etc.

Comment: The data from the DB is from a legacy CRM system that is several years old. The users added the spaces in about half the numbers for readability, as everything is stored as text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
WHERE replace(p.[Telephone], ' ', '') = '01279800101' 
OR replace(p.[Mobile], ' ', '') = '01279800101'
```

Comment: Somebody else suggested trim then deleted the answer, I thought I was commenting on that

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
WHERE REPLACE(p.[Telephone], ' ', '') = '0123456789'
```

It will replace all spaces in [Telephone] with empty string before